# java - tomcat - wep app multilanguage

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, freemarker

Yesterday I have made this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755641/java-freemarker-multilanguage-application

I had asked how to make a multilanguage site with Freemarker, I haven't an answer  yet so today my query is that:

Can I create a web app with multilanguage page? what is best way? and what is the best framework can I use?

I had started to learning tomcat 6 days ago so i'm noob please let me know if there is a way for do that.

Thank alot for the help
Andrea

Comment: How much do you know about java localization (l10n) and internationalizion (i18n)?  You need to understand how to deal with multiple languages in the first place before you can understand how to use them in Tomcat and Freemarker.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe Hi, i don't know anything about localization and internationalizion.... Can you give me a short explain me please or a guideline please? Thanks a lot

Comment: That is a broad question.  The basic idea is that you have a `ResourceBundle`.  This is loaded from a file and has your translations. For example, the key `key.house` would be `house` in the English file and `maison` in the French file.  You write all your output with keys and use the `ResourceBundle` to get final output. [Here is a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/). [Here is a book](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Internationalization-David-Czarnecki/dp/0596000197). Once you understand how to handle multiple languages in Java, it is easy to apply this knowledge to Freemarker.